# no puedo ejecutar una app con cordova android_sdk_root not found

Tags: android, ionic, cordova

ejecuto la app con `sudo ionic cordova run android --no-native-run`

y me da este error

```
Build at: 2021-03-12T15:33:11.989Z - Hash: 0988651d87acc69f295c - Time: 8191ms
> cordova run android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova run android exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

echo $PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/bug/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/bug/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk/tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/platform-tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/platform-tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/platform-tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/platform-tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/tools

sudo nano ~/.bash_profile

export ANDROID_HOME="/home/bug/Android/Sdk"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/bug/android-sdk/
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/bug/android-sdk/platform-tools:/home/bug/android-sdk/tools
```

Ahora tengo asi el /etc/profile

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools



sudo cordova requirements android --verbose
[sudo] password for bug:             
Platform API successfully found in: /home/bug/Escritorio/ionicapp/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: not installed 
Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Command failed with ENOENT: android list target
spawn android ENOENT
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
Some of requirements check failed
CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:422:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
bug@bug:~/Escritorio/ionicapp$
```

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas el mensaje de error

> Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable. Try setting it
> manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update
> your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

indica que el path definido para tu Android SDK es incorrecto o probablemente no existe, pero veo que usas `ANDROID_HOME`, es importan que sepas que su uso es obsoleto

[**`ANDROID_HOME` is deprecated and replaced with `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` by
android SDK.** It would be nice, if cordova also support
`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` variable to make it consistent with the SDK.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/949)

Usa únicamente:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="Ruta Android SDK"
```

pero asegura que en esa ruta en verdad se encuentre el Android SDK, en mi caso por ejemplo tengo definido:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/jorgesys/share/android-sdk
```

Comment: ya estoy usando android_sdk_root pero sigue sin pillarlo cordova. ya no sé que más puedo hacer

Answer (score -1):

Me econtré con el mismo problema siguiendo las instrucciones de la guía de inicio rápido de la página oficial de Cordova y más específicamente de aquí: [Android Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) donde dice:

> export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Development/android-sdk/

El problema es que en ese ejemplo usa el nombre de `android-sdk` pero no es como realmente se instala por defecto en el sistema. En mi instalación del Android Studio en Ubuntu 20.04, esa ruta es: `/home/MiUsuario/Android/Sdk/` y esa ruta sí la reconoció correctamente.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/302874)

Comment: @CandidMoe, he editado la respuesta para cumplir con lo que comentas. Aun así, no estoy del todo de acuerdo con tu afirmación puesto que el segundo párrafo explica cual es el problema, no me ciño a enlazar una web con la solución al problema en si. En cualquier caso, espero que ahora la respuesta quede más clara.